# How to type initial value in React Context of object data fetched from API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I cannot figure out how to type properly initial value of createContext.

This is what I have in the interface of data:

```
lineSectionsDefectsDetailsData: LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType;
```

And that's precisely the type:

```
export type LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType = {
    id: string;
    timestamp: Date;
    type: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    lineId: string;
    kilometer: number;
    coordinates: [];
    description: string;
};
```

When I type initial value as:

```
lineSectionsDefectsDetailsData: undefined,
```

I get below comment from typescript

[image]

Can You please suggest how to type in such situation properly initial value ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe setting it initially to null instead?

Comment: Will throw - Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `undefined` is a valid value for any `type` then you can use the `|` operator to define correct type definitions.

```
type LineSectionsDefectWarningDetailsType = {
  id: string;
  timestamp: Date;
  type: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  lineId: string;
  kilometer: number;
  coordinates: [];
  description: string;
} | undefined;
```